# The KML file contains invalid or unsupported data, or the file is too large to parse

Tags: html, kml

I've made a KML file which I want use to Google My Maps. In the map, when I click on Import > Select a file from you computer, I get the message "The file contains invalid or unsupported data, or the file is too large to parse." Why won't Google My Maps import my file?

Any help would be much appreciated.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document>
    <Folder>
      <name>PowerPoints/videos/posters/books</name>
      <Placemark>
        <name>Taranaki Basin Maari Oil Field</name>
        <description>
          <![CDATA[
            <p><a href="http://static.dgbes.com/images/PPT/Chimney-Atlas-Maari-OIl-Field.pptx" download>Download PowerPoint</a></p>
          ]]>
        </description>
        <Point>
          <coordinates>173.29406,-39.9861,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
      </Placemark>
      <Placemark>
        <name>Gippsland Basin West Seahorse Oil Field</name>
        <description>
          <![CDATA[
            <p><a href="http://static.dgbes.com/images/PPT/Chimney-Atlas-Seahorse-Oil-Field.pptx" download>Download PowerPoint</a></p>
          ]]>
        </description>
        <styleUrl>#icon-503-DB4436</styleUrl>
        <Point>
          <coordinates>147.622777777778,-38.2061111111111,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
      </Placemark>
      <Placemark>
        <name>Green Canyon 161 Genesis Oil Field</name>
        <description>
          <![CDATA[
            <p><a href="http://static.dgbes.com/images/PPT/Chimney-Atlas-Genesis-Oil-Field.pptx" download>Download PowerPoint</a></p>
          ]]>
        </description>
        <styleUrl>#icon-503-DB4436</styleUrl>
        <Point>
          <coordinates>-90.51773,27.77105,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
      </Placemark>
      <Placemark>
        <name>East Cameron 322 Oil Field</name>
        <description>
          <![CDATA[
            <p><a href="http://static.dgbes.com/images/PPT/Chimney-Atlas-E-Cameron-322-Oil-Field.pptx" download>Download PowerPoint</a></p>
          ]]>
        </description>
        <styleUrl>#icon-503-DB4436</styleUrl>
        <Point>
          <coordinates>-92.9720674,28.9457348,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
      </Placemark>
      <Placemark>
        <name>Molasse Basin Breitbrunn Gas Field</name>
        <description>
          <![CDATA[
            <p><a href="http://static.dgbes.com/images/PPT/Chimney-Atlas-Breitbrunn-Gas-Field.pptx" download>Download PowerPoint</a></p>
          ]]>
        </description>
        <styleUrl>#icon-503-DB4436</styleUrl>
        <Point>
          <coordinates>12.096273,47.895482</coordinates>
        </Point>
      </Placemark>
      <Placemark>
        <name>Enhancing DHI & Chimneys</name>
        <description>
          <![CDATA[
            <p><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IUoiEpgSrZY" target="_blank">View video</a></p>
          ]]>
        </description>
        <Point>
          <coordinates>50.851713,66.453241,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
      </Placemark>
      <Placemark>
        <name>Neural Networks & ChimneyCube</name>
        <description>
          <![CDATA[
            <p><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0NbAlmk-ITc" target="_blank">View video</a></p>
          ]]>
        </description>
        <Point>
          <coordinates>51.151148,-35.251312,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
      </Placemark>
      <Placemark>
        <name>Webinar Chimney Interpretation</name>
        <description>
          <![CDATA[
            <p><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p-qZe9-7Y4A" target="_blank">View video</a></p>
          ]]>
        </description>
        <Point>
          <coordinates>51.151148,-35.251312,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
      </Placemark>
      <Placemark>
        <name>Tutorial Processing & Interpretation</name>
        <description>
          <![CDATA[
            <p><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Eh76P_VSyEw" target="_blank">View video</a></p>
          ]]>
        </description>
        <Point>
          <coordinates>-88.4125,28.67611,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
      </Placemark>
      <Placemark>
        <name>Ranking Prospects</name>
        <description>
          <![CDATA[
            <p><a href="https://static.dgbes.com/images/PDF/workflow_hc-chimneys.pdf" target="_blank">View poster</a></p>
          ]]>
        </description>
        <Point>
          <coordinates>-88.4125,28.67611,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
      </Placemark>
      <Placemark>
        <name>Fluid Migration Path Interpretation</name>
        <description>
          <![CDATA[
            <p><a href="https://library.seg.org/doi/book/10.1190/1.9781560803119" target="_blank">Buy book</a></p>
          ]]>
        </description>
        <Point>
          <coordinates>-88.4125,28.67611,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
      </Placemark>
    </Folder>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

Answer (score 0):

A KML (as an XML file) must be well-formed and properly encoded.

One issue in the KML file is one of the entity reference is not escaped which is a fatal error in most XML parsers.

```
<name>Enhancing DHI & Chimneys</name>
```

The "&" in line above should be properly escaped and this line should be changed to following:

```
<name>Enhancing DHI &amp; Chimneys</name>
```

Same must be fixed in several other lines too; e.g. "Neural Networks & ChimneyCube", etc. Globally replace `" & "` with `" &amp; "` and should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I replaced all the `&` symbols with `&amp;` and it works, the file is now uploaded. However, this leaves me with another problem. Why is the HTML in the file not working?

Comment: If I publish the corrected KML into My Maps and click on a placemark, it downloads the referenced powerpoint file. What exactly in the HTML is not working? Please elaborate.

Comment: there are no margins around the `p` tags and instead of just showing the highlighted link name, it shows the link name and the url in paranthesis. I searched on Google and apparently Google My Maps does not parse HTML in KML files. It only works on Google Earth.